# What is the difference between thinning and skeletonizing?

Tags: algorithm

I know that this two method in image processing is quite similar. I want to know when I should use thinning or skeletonizing algorithm. So, is there any difference between thinning and skeletonizing?

Comment: read this http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm

Comment: @AliAmiri this article does not deal with the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the shape as something you "burn". Thinning is the same as setting all the borders on fire and waiting for a given time. The thinned image is what's left of the image after this time. With the same analogy skeletonizing again sets all the borders on fire but the result are the places where fire fronts meet.

In essence to implement these you can do a breadth first search from the borders of the shape. For Thinning the result are all the pixels not visited after a fixed number of steps of the BFS. The result of skeletonizing will consist of all the pixels in the last layer of the BFS. In a way you can think of skeletonizing as thinning as much as possible without loosing the image.

[image]

Apparently my image processing is better than my image producing, but the picture above demonstrates what is thinning(second rectangle - orange is removed) and skeletonizing - only the lines are left and called "skeleton".